# Flutter How to send Http (post) Request using WorkManager Plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest, flutter-workmanager

Hello Guys any help will be apprecited please,

I am unable to send Http post or get request using workmanager plugin in flutter, any solutions to this would be highly appreciated, thanks

Here is my code
any help will be appreciated
thanks

```
 Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
switch (task) {
  case fetchBackground:
    print('checkStatusnow');
    final sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pendingStat = sharedPref.getBool('pendingStat');
    print('pendingStat $pendingStat');
   // await initialStat();

    String url = 'https://getStat.com/chargeStat';

      try {
    var param = {
      'authorization_code': authoStatCode,
      'email': umail,
      'amount': StatFare *100,
      
    };
    String body= json.encode(param);
    var response = await http.Client().post(Uri.parse(url), headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': StatKey,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },body:  body,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

     
      print(response.body);
      print("Successfull");


      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
       print(data);
   

      if (StatFounds == null) {
        print("Status Not found");
      }
      else {
        print ('checkForSta');

      }

    }

    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
      print("not available");
    

      sharedPref.setBool("Stat", true);

    }

  } catch (e) {

  }
```

Comment: need some code how you try do this

Comment: Hello Novol, i have edited the post,  this is what i have tried, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello Novol any thoughts?

Comment: You need to at least print e from the catch to get some informations about what is going wrong or tell us what the response contains. But just a "doesn't work" is a bit too less to figure out the failure.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am also facing the same issue of not sending any http request.